# push a dynamic message in Scheduler websocket using spring boot using stomp

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I try to make a chatbot using springboot (websocket), i want to know if it's possible to push a dynamic message in Scheduler, and i need some help, i'can't fugure it out.
I want to push the message in the Scheduler Configure how could i do that:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

    @Autowired
    SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
    public void sendAdhocMessages() {
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/user", new UserResponse("Fixed Delay Scheduler"));
    }
}
```

in the sendAdhocMessages method i want to pass a message that will be displayed in an html page. in the Official doc it's impossible to pass a parameter to a method which is annotated by @Scheduled, is there any methd to do that?

Comment: Hi, could you find a solution or workaround for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) contains a hint to, how you could pass values to the scheduled method. Maybe you could provide a bean that acts as a message provider. In the scheduler class you autowire the message provider and request the messages.
A short code example:

```
@Componet
public class MessageProvider {
    private String message;

    // getter and setter ...
}
```

In the scheduler you could use the message provider like following:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

    @Autowired
    SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    MessageProvider messageProvider;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
    public void sendAdhocMessages() {
        String currentMessage = messageProvider.getMessage();
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/user", new UserResponse(currentMessage));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not realy what i mean to do, i want to call the sendAdhocMessages from another method and pass to it a parameter

Comment: the spring documentation is clear about the interface, you will not be able to pass a parameter to the scheduled method.